# SQL where clause doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm here again, with a problem. This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE subpagina='0'"; 
$q = $con->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $q->fetch();

if (count($row) != "0")
{
    echo '<ul>';
    while($row = $q->fetch())
    {
       echo '<li><a href="?page='. $row['ID'] . '">' . $row['pagina'] .'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';   
}
```

The problem is, all the records in the database where `subpagina = 0` will be echoed on the page. But, if I use another string like 3 in the database, and in this code, it doesn't work.

I have done some thing like `var_dump $row`, `var_dump(erroinfo())`, but it only returns `FALSE`.

I hope you can help me.

EDIT: here is my data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paginas` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pagina_link` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `pagina` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `reactie` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `subpagina` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=39 ;
```

EDIT2: here is the data

```
INSERT INTO `paginas` (`ID`, `pagina_link`, `content`, `pagina`, `reactie`, `subpagina`) VALUES
(32, '?pagina=Home', '<h1>Welkom!</h1><div>Dit is een demo van het cms combora! Je mag hier op uittesten. Je kan inloggen met als gebruikersnaam demo en paswoord demo. Gelieve deze pagina niet te verwijderen.</div><div><br></div> <a href="?pagina=Home&foto=2&l=j"><img width="250px" height="250px;" src="fotos/foto2.jpg"></a>', 'Home', '1', '0'),
(33, '?pagina=test1', '<br>dslmlmqdhfkqsjdf', 'test1', '1', '0'),
(34, '?pagina=test2', '<br>', 'test2', '0', '0'),
(35, '?pagina=Nice', 'fasdfdsfadsf<br>', 'Nice', '1', '0'),
(36, '?pagina=Foto viewer ', 'Deze pagina is een test van de zelfgemaakt foto viewer:<div><br></div>\r\n<a href=\\"?foto=1&amp;l=j\\"><img width=\\"250px\\" height=\\"250px;\\" src=\\"1.jpg\\"></a>\r\n<a href=\\"?foto=2&amp;l=j\\"><img width=\\"250px\\" height=\\"250px;\\" src=\\"2.jpg\\"></a>\r\n<a href=\\"?foto=3&amp;l=j\\"><img width=\\"250px\\" height=\\"250px;\\" src=\\"3.jpg\\"></a><div><br></div>', 'Foto viewer ', '1', '0'),
(38, 'sdkjfqsdfj', 'sdjmkqjfdmlkqsfdlmkqjsdflkjdlmskfjqslmdkfj', 'test56', '1', '2\r\n');
```

I'm not sure if you mention this?

Comment: print_r($row) what does it show?

Comment: can subpagina field be tinyint thus being interpreted as boolean on php side? (then 0 or 1 will work only)

Comment: Mm, the column in the database, is a integer.

Comment: `TINYINT` is not "interpreted as boolean on the PHP side"...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what the problem is...

Comment: If I print_r($row), if I use 0 It put out my data in the database, if I do it with a heigher valuen I put nothing in the browser.

Comment: So you mean that you have data in the database with `subpagina` other than `0`, but if you try to select it, it does not show?

Comment: Indeed Radu, that is correct!

Comment: @LEDfan The column is not an 'integer', but a 'varchar'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned it is a string. Try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE subpagina='0'";
```

Fiddled a limited set of your table. Added some data and the above SELECT simply works. So that's not the problem. Are you sure you have other strings than `'0'` in the `subpagina` field?

See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05d5c/2)

Another thing you can try is

There's no such thing as subagine = 3 in your data. Only 0 and 2 exist

```
$row = $q->fetchAll(); 
print_r($row);
/* print_r shows Array only */
/* loop the array and print the values */
foreach($row as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key + " " + $value + "\r\n";
}
```

**EDIT**

See it only just now: you do a `fetch()` assing it to `$row` and check the count. Then you start the while loop wiht anohter `fetch()` which will get the NEXT row of the result. The first one is skipped always because of the first `fetch()`

use something like this:

```
$rows = $q->fetchAll(); 

echo '<ul>';
foreach($rows as $value)
{
   echo '<li><a href="?page='. $value['ID'] . '">' . $value['pagina'] .'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

if you not want the empty `<ul>` tags you should check if `count($rows) > 0` before you echo/foreach/echo

Comment: I have try this multiple times. Thanks!

Comment: Post your table schema so we don't need to guess what datatypes you use

Comment: I have post it in my TP. I tried the query your showed allready. Thanks! If I fetchAll, it is output is: array( )

Comment: It is possible that my code isn't write, with the values, but It realley don't work!

Answer (score 1):

In the data you posted, I see that `subpagina` is actually a `VARCHAR` field, not a numeric field, and it has a value of `2\r\n`. You can fix this in multiple ways:

- `SELECT ... WHERE subpagina LIKE '2%'` to match the string `2` followed by anything else
- Fix the data and remove the extra `\r\n`
- The best way, if the data is indeed numeric, make that an `INTEGER` instead of `VARCHAR`

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved, I early treid it with a intenger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using strings to store what seem to be integers, but the problem you are having is that `'2\r\n'` !== `2`.

If you want to find `'2\r\n'` you need to look for exactly that or use a `LIKE` condition.